# changing "cameraDevice" to rear and front (beside UIImagePickerController)

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any other API that provide changing "cameraDevice" to rear and front? 
**beside "UIImagePickerController" 's cameraDevice property?**

Comment: i guess are taking about to use `imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;`

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of imagePickerController.cameraDevice variable but I hope to see if the other API has that control too. For my specific reason, I can not use UIImagePickerController API.

Comment: Than you can use [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: no it for ios development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function allowed me to solve the problem.

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCamera
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
    {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    return captureDevice;
}
```